# derivative of product of 2 inverse matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse

I was trying to differentiate the equation below:
$$
\frac{\partial a^T X^{-T}X^{-1}a} {\partial X}
$$
where X is  invertible but not symmetric and $X^{-T}$ means transpose of inverse of X.

In the above when there is no $X^{-T}$ then it can be done from math cookbook. Can anybody help me to solve that please?

Comment: You know the derivative of $X^{-1}$ with respect to $X$? If so, everything is linear; just use the product rule.

Comment: Could you please tell me something more about the differentiation.  $$ \frac{\partial X^{-1}_{(ij)} }{\partial X_{kl}}=-(X^{-1})_{ik}(X^{-1})_{lj}$$. But from there how do i proceed ? Thanks @user7530

Comment: $$\frac{\partial X^{-T}_{(ij)}}{\partial X_{kl}} = - (X^{-1})_{jk}(X^{-1})_{li} = (X^{-T})_{kj}(X^{-T})_{il}$$

Comment: Thanks for the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

By the product rule
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}} &= a^T\frac{\partial X^{-T}}{\partial x_{ij}}X^{-1}a + a^TX^{-T}\frac{\partial X^{-1}}{\partial x_{ij}} a\\
 &= a^T\frac{\partial (X^T)^{-1}}{\partial (x^T)_{ji}}X^{-1}a + a^TX^{-T}\frac{\partial X^{-1}}{\partial x_{ij}} a
\end{align*}

Now plug in the formula for the derivative of $X^{-1}$.

Comment: Continuing along the same line                                \begin{align*}                                       
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{ij}}  &= -a^TX^{-T}J^{ji}X^{-T}X^{-1}a - a^TX^{-T}X^{-1}J^{ij}X^{-1}a\\ &= -2(a^TX^{-T}X^{-1}J^{ij}X^{-1}a)\\ &=-2(X^{-T}X^{-1}aa^TX^{-T})_{ij}
\end{align*}                                                              
                                                                                                   So finally $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial X}=  -2X^{-T}X^{-1}aa^TX^{-T} $$    Hope i got it right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: X is a lower triangular matrix. Then does it change the answer?

Comment: It doesn't *change* the answer, since the answer is generically correct for all (square) matrices. However, it might *simplify* the answer, although I don't think it does so here since the inverse of a generic triangle matrix is dense.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me a lot. Tt might be a dumb question to ask. Since X is lower triangular, then would derivative also be a lower triangular  matrix, making upper elements  zero ?

Comment: Thanks! It helps me a lot.

Comment: The derivative of $X$ will also be triangular, but I don't think this translates into special structure for the derivative of $X^{-1}$.